# ntfs error after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ntfs

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HD, where windows7 is my old OS..I have set up a 50gb partition for installing Ubuntu. The partition is NTFS format. After installation Ubuntu is starting well, but when I choose Ubuntu from my dual boot OS option..Ubuntu stops booting & my screen blinking where nothing is visible...my laptop is a new one...what can I do to install Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on an NTFS partition? That's hardly possible, and even if you managed to install it (which I doubt), there is no way of booting such installation. You sure that Ubuntu did not format that partition?

Comment: you have to reinstall the system formatting the partition and making it ext4